# receive data from cc2640r2f(Texas instrument) and save it on Raspberry pi 4 with bluetooth

Tags: pi-4

I'm currently working on a project involving the Texas Instruments CC2640R2F board and the AD8232 sensor for ECG signal measurement. My goal is to receive ECG data on the CC2640R2F board,and then transfer it to a Raspberry Pi 4 using bluetooth for recording into a file for further processing. While I've managed to obtain ECG data on the CC2640R2F board, I'm encountering difficulties in transferring it to the Raspberry Pi 4 and correctly recording it. I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to accomplish this task
Thanks in advance for your assistance!